# apache tomcat: error in startup grails application

Tags: apache, grails, tomcat7

I've deployed a Grails war into a server in which I've installed Apache Tomcat 7, but it does not start.
Here is the stacktrace, given in catalina.out:

```
2014-07-05 12:07:55,875 [http-bio-8080-exec-53] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invo
cation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
    ... 5 more
2014-07-05 12:07:55,883 [http-bio-8080-exec-53] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in
ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on
null object
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invo
cation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot       invoke method getAt() on null object
    at    com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
    ... 5 more
2014-07-05 12:07:55,886 [http-bio-8080-exec-53] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  -     Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletC
 ontext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;  nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null obj 
 ect
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invo
cation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot    invoke method getAt() on null object
     at      com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.j ava:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
     ... 5 more
```

Any suggestion about it?

EDIT:
the tomcat version in which war does not work is 7.0.54. I've previously used, in another machine, an earlier version (7.0.26) and war starts.

Comment: how does `run-war` / `prod run-app` turns out?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean Mario? If you mean how I run the app, I use the Start button in Apache Tomcat App Manager

Comment: what i meant was, does the same thing happen when you use the grails interactive console to start the app in the embedded tomcat server (in production mode). In general it would be good, if you tell us a little more about the context and what you have already tried out

Comment: I've never used the grails interactive console to start the app. In production I use Intellij Idea IDE and the app starts correctly. I've put the app in another server and it starts too, but in the first server (that is a virtual remote one) I have the above exception

Comment: For me it was a combination of Java 8 and tomcat 7.0.54 that caused the error. Downgrading to Java 7 and tomcat 7.0.26 solved the issue.

Comment: Downgrading to java 7 solve this for me because i am using tomcat 7.0.59

Comment: Just downgrading the java version was enough for me to fix it. (Note this involves changing JAVA_HOME in both bin/setenv.bat/sh and conf/wrapper.conf)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem trying to run my Grails 2.2.4 project on Ubuntu 16.04 beta and as Tomasz mentioned in the comment, it seems to be a combination of an old Grails version, Java 8 and newer versions of tomcat. Both tomcat 7 and tomcat 8 have the same issue. **I solved the problem by upgrading my Grails project to Grails 2.3.11**, which was as far as I could go without massive refactoring of the code. Switching to older tomcat or Java 7 was not an option for me.

Comment: Wrong java version (8 instead of 7) caused this problem for me and this answer helped me solve it. Thanks!